# JPA one to one mapping

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have following table structure with one to one mapping.

```
public class Parent {
 private long parentPK(Parent primary key); 
 private Child child;

    @OneToOne(
        cascade = {CascadeType.ALL },
        fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
        mappedBy = "child"
    )
    public Child getChild() {
        return this.child;
    } 
}

public class Child{

private long childPK(Child primary key); 
private Parent parentFK;(parent foreign key)

   @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(
        name = "PARENT_FK",
        referencedColumnName = "PARENT_PK"
    )
    public Parent getParentFK() {
        return this.parentFK;
    }
}
```

Note: Parent table does not have reference to child table. Child holds parent primary key as foreign key column. Here primary key for parent and child is different.

As per my requirement, on persisting parent, child record should be automatically persisted without explicitly setting foreign key to child table.
Executing with the above structure resulting "Can not insert non-null record for PARENT_FK in CHILD table".
Could someone kindly guide on possibility of achieving above requirement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mapping is incorrect.

The main problem you have here is your `mappedBy = “child”` refers to the child attribute on the `Child` class – not the `Parent` class. There is no child attribute on the child class and you need instead to refer to the `parentPK` attribute on the `Child` class.

I suggest to keep PK/FK out of entity field names as it can be a little confusing.

Below are the updated Parent/Child entities.
(I’ve switched to field access but that’s just my preference)

```
@Entity
public class Child  {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "childPK")
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(
        name = "PARENT_FK",
        referencedColumnName = "PARENT_PK"
    )
        private Parent parent;

@Entity
public class Parent {

    @Id 
    @Column(name = "PARENT_PK")
    private long id;

        @OneToOne(
        cascade = {CascadeType.ALL},
        fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
 -->    mappedBy = "parent")  //Refers to parent field of the Child class

        private Child child;
```

Note that you have defined a bidirectional OneToOne relationship. In JPA bidirectional relationships have an owning side – the side with the join information, *Child* in you case – and an inverse side – the side with the mappedBy attribute, *Parent* in your case. It’s a good idea to get to grips with this.  This reference looks at OneToOne relationships and  there are plenty others around. https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/OneToOne

Answer (score 1):

Your mapping is correct, and you haven't provided the save code for the save operation.

But you can't save the child without giving a reference to the parent, you will not have to set the foreign key but in your save method you should do both these:

```
parent.setChild(child);
child.setParent(parent);
```

Answer (score 0):

I did face something similar.Your mapping and everything looks good. It looks like you have set Parent entity of the Child and not set Parent to this Child entity. That is you are trying to save child without setting its parent.So may be you will need to do someting like this:

```
Parent p= new Parent();
Child c = new Child();
p.setChild(c);
// c.setParent(p);    Looks like this is missing in your code
session.save();
```